# Padding of buttons too big

Tags: css, button, navigation, padding

I've been trying to change all my properties in my CSS in order to fix my current problem with my navigation bar buttons, but in vain.

When hovered over, the buttons exceeds the height of the navigation-bar background, which they aren't supposed to.

http://www.mohrdevelopment.com

My HTML:

```
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><em class="home"/>Home</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="second.html"><em class="photos"/><b>Photos</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.html"><em class="projects"/><b>Projects</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html"><em class="about"/><b>About</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"><em class="contact"/><b>Contact</b></a></li>
            </ul>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
        font-family:sans-serif;
        background: url(images/background3.png);
    }

    .navigation {
        background:#1841c8 url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_background.png);
        height:40px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        font-size: 0; /*remove whitespace*/
        display:block;
        min-width:625px;
    }

    .navigation li{
        display:inline-block;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size:16px;
            }

    .navigation li a{
        display:block;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        padding: 11px 5px 15px;
    }

    .navigation li a em{
        height:32px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0 5px 6px 50px;
        font-weight:bold;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-position: 0 50%;
        font-size:16px;
    }

    .navigation li a:hover{
        color:#00CCFF;
        background: url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_hover.png);
        text-decoration:none;
        padding: 11px 5px 10px;
    }

    .navigation .current a {
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background:url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_hover.png);
        padding-bottom:11px;
    }


    /*Navigation bar icons*/
    .navigation li a em.home {
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/home.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    .navigation li a em.photos{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/Photo.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }


    .navigation li a em.projects{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/projects.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }


    .navigation li a em.about{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/about.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .navigation li a em.contact{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/Contact.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    a {
      Color:blue;
      Text-decoration:none;
    }

    h1 {
        background: url(images/Header.png);
        text-indent:-9999px;
        width:1092px;
        height:132px;
        margin:auto;

    }


    .content, aside {
        height:600px;
    }

    .wrap {
          margin:auto;
          width:80%;
          background:yellow;
        }

    .content {
        background:teal;
        float:left;
        width:80%;
        height:auto;
        min-width:500px;
        display:inline;

    }

    aside {
        background:lightblue;
        float:left;
        width:20%;
        min-width:125px;
        display:inline;
    }

    aside ul {
        padding-left:1px;
        list-style:none;
    }


    ul a {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #666;
    }

    ul a:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
        color:black;
    }

    .sidebarli {
    }

    li {
        list-style:none;
        margin-bottom:20px;}

    label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #292929;
        font-family:sans-serif;
        padding-bottom:8px;
    }

    form ul {padding-left:0px;
    }

    textarea {
        width:400px;
        height:220px;

    }
```

Comment: Your entire HTML structure is extremely weird - you're using em elements instead of divs (it would seem), you are nesting li and em elements inside each other in the menu etc etc. I don't mean to sound like a jackass but I think you need to properly learn basic HTML before going onto more advanced projects.

Comment: Should i use divs internally in the <ul>?

Comment: <ul> should contain only <li> in the topmost level, and those <li> can contain <a> tags if neeeded. You should also, absolutely, definitely, not use <em> tags like you are. <em> is used to put emphasis on text, not to segment content. Like I said - you really should study HTML and learn it properly before trying to construct a page like this.

Comment: I'm aware that i should study HTML. But i'm using video tutorials from  various sites, tutsplus is my favorite one. But the videos only covers html coding til a certain point. I've been struggling looking for more advanced tutorials.

Comment: You should consider reading a book where you can go at your own pace, test out stuff properly and then go back when you need to. A great (text) resource is W3Schools - http://www.w3schools.com/html . Also what I'm talking about is in no way 'advanced' - using <div> for content segmentation is one of the first things you learn. Never copy code you don't understand, build stuff from the ground up and make sure you _understand what you are doing_, not just making sure it works somehow.

Comment: Thank you. Surely something to take into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think issue lies in Navigation/Navigation/nav_hover.png image. You are applying repeat to your background image.

Please use

```
.navigation li a:hover 
{
    background: url("Navigation/Navigation/nav_hover.png") **no-repeat** scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #00CCFF;
    padding: 11px 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

in style.css.

Let me know if this fixed the issue.

Comment: :) this happens. Don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust the padding on the A element:

```
.navigation li a {
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

Also, your "em" tags should be closed. You've got opening "em" tags but no closing "/em" tags.

Comment: Your hover state also includes padding.

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question. :) And I think we might be interpreting his question differently. But it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Doesn't really help. And i have <em /> tags. Am i not allowed to close it initially instead of writing <em></em>?

Comment: Oh, it helped now that i changed the hover state aswell. Thank you :)

Comment: Ah fair enough, I misunderstood the issue.